# Append Facebook tracking event to Order received page in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

I'm looking to add a Facebook tracking event which includes purchase amount & currency to a WooCommerce purchase confirmation page, without resorting to a plugin.

I assumed something like the following would do the job in the functions.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Append Facebook tracking Event
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'facebook_tracking_thank_you_page' );

function facebook_tracking_thank_you_page() {
    $currency = $order->get_order_currency();
    $total = $order->get_total();
echo ("<script>fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '<?php echo $total ?>',currency: '<?php echo $currency?>'});</script>");
}
?>
```

However, the script isn't echoed on the confirmation page at all. It also breaks the layout of the page.

I've now tried adding the echo statement to the global header (wrapped in an if statement targeting that specific page):

**Header.php**

```
<!-- Echo Facebook Tracking on Checkout -->
<?php
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'page' && $post->ID == '3327'){
        echo "<script>fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '<?php echo $total ?>',currency: '<?php echo $currency?>'});</script>";
    }
?>
```

**While keeping this in the functions.php file:**

```
/**
 * Append Facebook tracking Event
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'facebook_tracking_thank_you_page' );

function facebook_tracking_thank_you_page() {
    $currency = $order->get_order_currency();
    $total = $order->get_total();
}
```

However, all I'm seeing outputted on the page is this:

```
<script>fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '<?php echo  ?>',currency: '<?php echo ?>'});</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many errors and mistakes in your code.

- The `$order` variable is not defined
- You need to add the missing argument `$order_id` in your hooked function
- You need to get the instance of the `WC_Order` object from the **Order ID**
- The `WC_Order` method `get_order_currency()` is deprecated and replaced by `get_currency()`
- And some others…

Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'facebook_tracking_thank_you_page', 90, 1 );
function facebook_tracking_thank_you_page( $order_id ) {
    // Get the WC_Order instance Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Output
    echo "<!-- Facebook tracking event -->
    <script>fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '".$order->get_total()
    ."',currency: '".$order->get_currency()."'});</script>";
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: That's perfect thank you. Exactly what I was trying to find.